# Eclipse: Add a shortcut key for an ActionContributedItem

Tags: eclipse

In the IDE I use for development, I have a view with a list viewer. Whenever I right click on an item, a list of menu items appears and one of the menu item is more frequently used by me. This menu is not contributed as a 'Command', hence, I'm unable to add short key in the preference dialog. is there a way to add short cut key for the Menu item?

Code solution are also welcome, because, I can added a new Plugin and drop into the plugins folder and use it?

Kindly, Help me set up a shortcut for the menu item

Answer (score 1):

The key binding service (`IBindingService`) always works on command ids so you must define a command and set the key binding for that.

You can set a command id for an `Action` (or `IAction`) by calling the

```java
setActionDefinitionId("command id")
```

method (the odd method name is for historical reasons).

Comment: Thanks Greg, is there a way to get the Action (corresponding to the menu item) instance with the ID?

Comment: `ActionContributionItem` has a `getAction` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg :)